# The cellForItemAtIndexPath for UICollectionView not be called (without using storyboard)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am new for IOS development , and I try to use `UIcollectionView` to show the photo.

**I am not using `storyboard`.**

I create a `xib file` call `AITFileCell_grid.xib` , and add a `Collection View Cell` like the following picture.

[image]

And create the another `xib file` call `AITLocalGridViewController.xib` for adding `UICollectionView` into the `View`.

When I call `reloadData` , **the return value of `numberOfItemsInSection` more than 1.**
But `cellForItemAtIndexPath` is not be called.

I have set the `dataSource` and `delegate` like the following picture.
[image]

**------------------------------------------EDIT----------------------------------------------**

I have add the Identifier for `AITFileCell_grid.xib` like the following picture.

[image]

The following code is in **`AITLocalGridViewController.h`**.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AITFileCell_grid.h"

@interface AITLocalGridViewController : UICollectionViewController <UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;

@end
```

The following code is in **`AITLocalGridViewController.m`**.

```
#import "AITLocalGridViewController.h"
#import "AITFileCell_grid.h"
#import "VLCMovieViewController.h"

@interface AITLocalGridViewController ()<UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate>
{
    NSString *directory ;
    NSArray *fileList ;
    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath ;

    UIDocumentInteractionController *documentInteractionController ;

}
@end

@implementation AITLocalGridViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization

    }
    return self;
}

- (NSArray *)getFileList
{
    NSLog(@"getFileList...@@@");
    if (directory) {
        NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:directory error:NULL];

        return directoryContent;
    }
    return [[NSArray alloc] init] ;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad...@");
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib. 

    [self.collectionView registerClass:[AITFileCell_grid class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"AITFileCell_grid"];



    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    if([paths count] > 0) {
        directory = [paths objectAtIndex:0] ;
    }


}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated] ;
    fileList = [self getFileList] ;
    NSLog(@"viewDidAppear...fileList@@...%@" , fileList);

    [self.collectionView reloadData];
    [AITFileCell_grid startThumbnailFetching] ;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    NSLog(@"didReceiveMemoryWarning...@@@@");
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Collection view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    NSLog(@"numberOfSectionsInCollectionView...@");
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"numberOfItemsInSection...@...%lu", (unsigned long)[fileList count]);
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [fileList count];
}


- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSLog(@"cellForItemAtIndexPath...@@");
//    AITFileCell_grid *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:[AITFileCell_grid reuseIdentifier] forIndexPath:indexPath];

    AITFileCell_grid *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"AITFileCell_grid" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.fileName.text = [fileList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ;

    NSDictionary * fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", directory, [fileList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] error:nil] ;

    double fileSize = [fileAttributes fileSize] ;

    NSString *sizeString = @"0" ;
    if (fileSize < 1024) {

        sizeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", fileSize] ;
    } else {
        fileSize /= 1024 ;
        if (fileSize < 1024) {

            sizeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2fKB", fileSize] ;
        } else {
            fileSize /= 1024 ;
            if (fileSize < 1024) {

                sizeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2fMB", fileSize] ;
            } else {
                fileSize /= 1024 ;
                if (fileSize < 1024) {

                    sizeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2fGB", fileSize] ;
                } else {

                }
            }
        }
    }

    cell.fileSize.text = sizeString ;

    NSDateFormatter *form = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [form setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"] ;

    cell.filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", directory, [fileList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]] ;

    [AITFileCell_grid fetchThumbnail:cell] ;

    return cell;

}

@end
```

I have set the `dataSource` and `delegate` , and the **value return of `numberOfItemsInSection` more than 1.**

****But the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` not be called after `numberOfItemsInSection` has been called.**

**I'm not sure the `AITFileCell_grid` has been register or not...**

**But it doesn't show the cell on the cell.**

Could some one help me and teach me how to do ?

Comment: Just add Collection view cell from side menu...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to add UICollectionViewDataSource protocol to your controller @interface.

Then, add Collection view cell to your coll. view

[image]

Also, didn't forget add reuse identifier:
you can for ex. "Cell"

[image: identifier]

Comment: Should I add reuse identifier if I already write `[self.collectionView registerNib:nib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:[AITFileCell_grid reuseIdentifier]];` ?

Comment: Of course you should because this property use value from field on picture

Comment: I have add the code for `AITLocalGridViewController.m` , it has add protocol to your controller `@interface`.

Comment: I add `FileCell` for `Reuse Identifier`. But the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` for `UICollectionView` still not be called...

Comment: can you send me project to mvadim@me.com i try to check whats wrong

Comment: I have send you a `zip file` for code of `collectionView`. Di you receive the mail ?

Comment: Excuse me , do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I have got same issue with both tableview and collectionview, sometimes method registerClass does not work. Have you tried load the nib file and then register it? It should work.

```
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"AITFileCell_grid" bundle:nil];
[self.collectionView registerNib:nib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"AITFileCell_grid"];
```

Comment: Sorry, I haven't read through ur question .It may be not issue with your custom cell. is the method really collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: not be called? Only 2 reasons:
- return of number section = 0
- return number of cells = 0
Can you print and show the log of filelist array.

Answer (score -1):

`cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is a [`UITableViewDataSource`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) method. That is for use with table views, not collection views. You should implement the methods of [`UICollectionViewDataSource`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewDataSource_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UICollectionViewDataSource) if you are using a collection view, and set that object to be the data source for your collection view.

Comment: Sorry...I make mistake. It is `cellForItemAtIndexPath` not `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. What you mean for **set that object to be the data source for your collection view** ? Is it like the picture which I post ?

Comment: Excuse me , do you have any idea?